# codeigniter, echo data from model to view PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have looked through all the relative data on this site to try and find a resolution that works for me but, I have not found one. I have been at this for hours, after exhausting all my options (trying). I have finally decided to ask for help. I need to echo the data from the model to the view to see if I am doing this right (testing). I am trying to learn this framework (Codeigniter)  my own. I have the following setup...

**Controller**:

```
<?php
class csv extends CI_Controller
{
public $data;
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('csvToJson');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('uploadCsvForm');

}
function uploadData()
{
    $this->csvToJson->uploadData();
    redirect('csv');

}
}
?>
```

**model**:

```
<?php
// php class to convert csv to json format
class csvToJson extends CI_Model{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function uploadData()
{
    $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");

    //read csv headers
    $key = fgetcsv($fp,"1024",",");

    // parse csv rows into array
    $json = array();
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp,"1024",",")) 
    {
        $json[] = array_combine($key, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
    return json_encode($json);

}
}// end class
?>
```

**View**:

```
 <form action="<?php echo site_url();?>csv/uploadData" method="post" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Choose a CSV file: </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile" 
              id="userfile"  align="center"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-9">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-
                 info">upload</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what exactly do you want to show on view?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 2):

To view the data on view you need to pass in through controller

```
function uploadData()
{
$data = $this->csvToJson->uploadData();
$this->load->view('uploadCsvForm',$data);
}
```

Comment: just need to echo out my json data in the view so i can test and make sure its working.

Comment: updated to:   function uploadData()
    {
        $data = $this->csvToJson->uploadData();
        //$this->csvToJson->uploadData();
        $this->load->view('uploadCsvForm',json_encode($data));
        redirect('csv');

    }                                                                                                                                 <?php
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
and getting an error : A PHP Error was encountered

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/uploadCsvForm.php

Line: 19

uploadCsvForm.php
Line: 19

Comment: change it to `$data['anyName']=$this->csvToJson->uploadData()` and access `$anyName` in your view

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Data in your function in which you are calling the view, and then pass that Data to the view. For example in your Controller

```
public function index()
{
  $data['files']=$this->yourModel->getDataFunction();
  $this->load->view('path/to/your/view',$data);
}
```

In your Model

```
public function getDataFunction()
{
  return $this->db->query('your query')->result();
}
```

In your View

```
<?php foreach($files as $file){?>
      <h2><?php echo $files['title']?></h2>
<?php endforeach?>
```

For File uploading or Form Posting your might wanna look at [Form Validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) and [File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 1):

ok, got it working with the following :

In **Controller**:

```
function uploadData()
{
    $data['json'] = $this->csvToJson->uploadData();
    $this->load->view('uploadCsvForm',$data);
}
```

In **View**:

```
<?php
$data = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $data;
?>
```

looks like we are good too, csv is parsing to JSON

Comment: Can you not do <code>$this->load->view('uploadCsvForm', json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));</code> in your controller and not have to mess around in the view?